# workflow designer 2010

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

i'm using sharepoint designer 2010, custom list.
I have created simlpe workflow.

**the workflow:**
1. collect data from user.
2. Update list item.

I recive a task, fill-in data, and then I expected to see the item update
but I do not see nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use Collect Data from a user you'll get a return variable for the ID of the new task item.

Let's say you create a new Collect Data from a user with a custom form field "Collect Something", this is done in the Custom Task Wizard.

After you have set that up the action will create an output variable, by default named "collect". This is the variable that holds the ID to the task created.

Then you crate a new action for Update item. Lets say you want to update the Title of the Current Item.

1. Click the "fx" button
2. Set the Data source to your Task List
3. Field from source: The custom form field created, that would be Collect Something in this case.
4. Under the Find the List Item, set Field: ID and the Value: collect (the variable from the Collect Data from a user)

This should work, if its another problem some more info is needed :)